# vQmod and OCmod duplicating modifications

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

I'm using vQmod 2.5.1 and Opencart 2.0.3.1, and I've run into an interesting problem.

I've got a vQmod xml that makes some modifications to the `system/library/cart.php` file. Here's an example:

```
<file name="system/library/cart.php">
    <operation>
       <search position="after"><![CDATA[private $data]]></search>
       <add><![CDATA[private $cr_prices = false;]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

I've placed this file in vQmod's xml directory and am not using OCmod at all for this. It was fine at first, but later I had to refresh Opencart's modification cache for another xml that uses OCmod, and suddenly my entire page broke.

It turns out OCmod created a copy of `system/library/cart.php` using the modifications from my vQmod xml, and then vQmod made a modification of that file, duplicating all the modifications. So the above modification created these two lines:

```
private $cr_prices = false;
private $cr_prices = false;
```

And I got a PHP error about redeclaring class properties.

Anyone run into this problem before or know how to fix it? Why is OCmod applying changes that are in the `vqmod/xml` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Heh, after hours of pouring through the core code turns out this wasn't really a problem with vQmod nor with OCmod themselves, but with an extension I used to install vQmod. I completely forgot I had installed vQmod using [this extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19501)...

I have uninstalled the extension and have installed vQmod via the official tutorial:

https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart

Now things are working as they should.